# How to grab ctrl + f keyboard event on input to handle custom search on a page in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using the virtual scrollbar of Angular 4 on a web page(in virtual scrollbar the list is loaded at runtime), but <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> functionality is not working on the data that is not present in the DOM at some particular point of time.
So to make <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> work, the idea is to grab the input string from<kbd>ctrl+f</kbd>  dialogue and search that string from the list and render that item on its search.
I need the whole string, every time the user enters the key in <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> dialogue.
How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your component. In ngAfterViewInit

```
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
        // Do your stuff here 
        // e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

[Stackblitz](https://angular-4mkja4.stackblitz.io)

Comment: I do not have to prevent default instead I have to grab every input element from the find dialogue(which appears on ctrl + f). In your case, the event will we fired only when ctrl+f is pressed and after that, any key is pressed will not be fired.

Answer (score 2):

Write a directive:

```
export class CtrlFDetectorDirective {

    @Output() ctrlF: EventEmitter<boolean>=new EventEmitter();
    constructor() {
    }

    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (event.getModifierState && event.getModifierState('Control') && event.keyCode===70) {
            this.ctrlF.emit(true);
        }
    }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-98v1xw)

Comment: I have to grab every input element from the find dialogue(which appears on ctrl + f). In your case, the event will we fired only when ctrl+f is pressed and after that, any key is pressed will not be fired.